# Hi, Trying to find VBA code to import group of XML files to Map (A) A long with the XML File name

Tags: xml, vba

this code i found it here, but it missed the first file name as well as the right arrange of the file names,
example if i have 3 XML file A,B&C the result will Show B&C only in "filename column", while (B Occupy the cells of A) and (C occupy the cells of B)

---

```vb
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub LoopThroughFiles()
        Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, Num As Long, LR As Integer
        Dim lngStart, lngEnd As Long
    
        strPath = "M:\B\XML\"
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")
        Num = 0
    
        lngStart = 2 'considering row 1 has headers. if not change it to 1.
        While strFile <> ""
    
            ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("A").Import URL:= _
            (strPath & strFile)
    
            strFile = Dir
    
            Num = Num + 1
    
            lngEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("AI" & lngStart & ":AI" & lngEnd).Value = strFile
    
            lngStart = lngEnd + 1
    
        Wend
    
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully for " & Num & " XML file(s)", vbInformation
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was t change the location of (strFile = Dir)

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, Num As Long, LR As Integer
    Dim lngStart, lngEnd As Long

    strPath = "M:\B\XML\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")
    Num = 0

    lngStart = 2 'considering row 1 has headers. if not change it to 1.
    While strFile <> ""

        ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("A").Import URL:= _
        (strPath & strFile)

        

        Num = Num + 1

        lngEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("AI" & lngStart & ":AI" & lngEnd).Value = strFile

        lngStart = lngEnd + 1
        strFile = Dir

    Wend

MsgBox "This code ran successfully for " & Num & " XML file(s)", vbInformation

End Sub
```